# Check if Android app is installed returns an error when checking a second time

Tags: java, android

I want to check if an Android app is installed with this code:

```java
if (isAppInstalled("com.anydo")) {
    textview3.setText("TRUE");
} else {
    textview3.setText("FALSE");
}
```

```java
private boolean isAppInstalled(String uri) {
    android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
    return false;
}
```

It actually work, but I want to check an app again and I use same if code, but it returns an error.

I'm using this `if(isAppInstalled("com.anydo")) {} else {}`

how to fix that ?

my example code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B1ypjgxSLOO7Hvm2tgmPK65obujZR381/view?usp=drivesdk

my error code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B4jtcxGPp2O4qIbKGya18EmHegEXd4ZX/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: it would be great if you show the actual error

Answer (score 1):

Try this code;

```
 public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
        try {
            return context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).enabled;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can this check one more condition ?